# Delphi 2010: No thread vs threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm user of delphi 2010, my current machine is intel core i7, running windows 7 x64. I've write the following codes:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCount: Integer;
    FTickCount: Cardinal;
    procedure DoTest;
    procedure OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FMethod: TProc;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const aCreateSuspended: Boolean; const aMethod: TProc);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
    T1, T2: Cardinal;
begin
  T1 := GetTickCount;
  for i := 0 to 9 do
    DoTest;
  T2 := GetTickCount;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('no thread=%4f', [(T2 - T1)/1000]));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var T: TMyThread;
    i: integer;
begin
  FCount := 0;
  FTickCount := GetTickCount;

  for i := 0 to 9 do begin
    T := TMyThread.Create(True, DoTest);
    T.OnTerminate := OnTerminate;
    T.Priority := tpTimeCritical;

    if SetThreadAffinityMask(T.Handle, 1 shl (i mod 8)) = 0 then
      raise Exception.Create(IntToStr(GetLastError));

    Inc(FCount);
    T.Start;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoTest;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10000000 do
    IntToStr(i);
end;

procedure TForm1.OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Dec(FCount);
  if FCount = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('thread=%4f', [(GetTickCount - FTickCount)/1000]));
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(const aCreateSuspended: Boolean; const aMethod:
    TProc);
begin
  inherited Create(aCreateSuspended);
  FMethod := aMethod;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  FMethod;
end;
```

Click on Button1 will shows 12.25 seconds, while Button2 will shows 12.14 seconds. My problem is why i cannot get more obvious difference of time taken (less than 10 seconds) although i'm running parallel threads ?

Comment: please remember to format your question next time

Comment: tpTimeCritical doesn't do what you think it does. Thread priority doesn't make your threads run faster; it simply makes them preempt any other threads that are currently running that have a lower priority. For example, the IDE's main thread might be one of these threads; you could potentially be unable to break into the process when debugging. Thread priority only makes a practical difference when there's contention for the processor, i.e. another thread going to and staying at 100% on a core. Using thread priority for other things (like synchronization) is a bug and shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory allocation seems to be the main problem here.

If you replace the payload with

```
procedure TForm6.DoTest;
var i: integer;
  a: double;
begin
  a := 0;
  for i := 1 to 10000000 do
    a := Cos(a);
end;
```

the code will parallelize nicely indicating that there's no real problem with your framework.

If you, however, replace the payload with memory allocation/deallocation

```
procedure TForm6.DoTest;
var i: integer;
  p: pointer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10000000 do begin
    GetMem(p, 10);
    FreeMem(p);
  end;
end;
```

the parallel version will run much slower than the single-threaded one.

When calling IntToStr, a temporary string is allocated and destroyed and this allocations/deallocations are creating the bottleneck.

BTW1: Unless you really really know what you're doing, I'm strongly advising against running threads at tpTimeCritical priority. Even if you really really know what you're doing you shouldn't be doing that.

BTW2: Unless you really really know what you're doing, you should not mess with affinity masks on thread level. System is smart enough to schedule threads nicely.

Comment: To complete this answer: when the IsMultiThread global variable is set to True (and usint TThread sets it to True), usually memory managers have to protect memory allocation requests from concurrent threads. This adds some overhead that can actually slow down an application, if memory allocations are the hot spot.

Comment: To complete Idsandor's addition :) Delphi 2010 memory manager (i.e. FastMM) keeps different allocation sizes in different blocks and each block is protected by its own lock. If the threads are allocating differently sized areas, they won't block each other. In this case, however, all allocations came from the same block and memory manager's lock forces thread serialization.

Comment: In FastMM4 you can also set the define AssumeMultiThreaded, and it will skip the checks "if IsMultiThread then", always using the MT code. It will result in a performance penaly for single-threaded applications, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you have memory intensive threads (many memory allocations/deallocations) you better use TopMM instead of FastMM: http://www.topsoftwaresite.nl/

FastMM uses a lock which blocks all other threads, TopMM does not so it scales much better on multi cores/cpus!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but there's a chance that the OnTerminate event is called from the context of the TThread. If that's the case (I must admit I haven't checked this), you'd be better off using `InterlockedDecrement` on FCount, and synchronizing the GUI updates. Just a minor point, but in production code these things matter.